# Get properties of object from list

Tags: python

Consider an object `customer` and a list of properties `attrs`. **How might one iterate over the list to get the properties from the list?**

```
class Human():     
    name = 'Jenny'         
    phone = '8675309'

customer = Human()
attrs = ['name', 'phone']

print(customer.name)    # Jenny
print(customer.phone)    # 8675309

for a in attrs:
    print(customer.a)    # This doesn't work!
    print(customer[a])    # Neither does this!
```

I am specifically targeting Python3 (Debian Linux) but a Python2 answer would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(customer, a)
```

---

```
>>> class Human:
...     name = 'Jenny'
...     phone = '8675309'
...
>>> customer = Human()
>>> for a in ['name', 'phone']:
...     print(getattr(customer, a))
...
Jenny
8675309
```